# How to convert to 3 decimal point

Tags: sql, formatting, format

I created this query to find the AVG of miles traveled, but I'm struggling to format the data to 3 decimal point.

> 49.614112472330234

```
SELECT AVG(Mileage_Used)/SUM(time_to_sec(timediff(Lesson_Finish_Time,Lesson_Time))/3600) as Mileage_per_hour from LESSONS;
```

Answer (score 1):

Cast the value to a decimal type with the right precision:

```
select cast(<yourvalue> as decimal(10,3))
```

In your case:

```
SELECT cast(AVG(Mileage_Used)/SUM(time_to_sec(timediff(Lesson_Finish_Time,Lesson_Time))/3600) as decimal(10,3)) as Mileage_per_hour 
from LESSONS
```

Comment: thanks for the query but there is a syntax issue with your example.

Comment: @user2277471 oops. Fixed now.

Comment: I was using this. SELECT CAST(AVG(Mileage_Used) AS Decimal(10,3))/SUM(time_to_sec(timediff(Lesson_Finish_Time,Lesson_Time))/3600) as MILAGE 
from LESSONS;

Comment: hmm yours gives a better rounding up compared to mine.